# Recover initial list of merge conflicts

Tags: git, git-merge, git-reflog

When git encounters conflicts upon merging, a list is displayed, where every entry begins with `CONFLICT` and contains information about the reason of the conflict, like `(renamed/deleted)`.

I am looking for a way to retrieve this *exact* list after rebooting the machine or merely closing the CLI.

There is of course:

```
git diff --name-only --diff-filter=U
```

However this does not contain information about the reason for the conflict, so finding this out for 50+ files is more effort than resetting git and redoing the merge.

Can this be achieved, *e.g.* using `reflog`?

EDIT: Please note, this question refers specifically to the list described, I am not asking for other solutions to resolve merge conflicts.

Comment: Unfortunately, Git drops some of the important information after detecting a rename/rename conflict. If there is *only one* such conflict, it's recoverable, otherwise it's tricky. (I think this applies to rename/delete conflicts as well—renames in general aren't quite recorded correctly.)

Comment: I try to reproduce a similar conflict to analyse the situation better. @Mär, Could you indicate me the version of Git you are using please?

Comment: @padawin Version: `2.21.0.windows.1`, however before you decide to dive in - I suspect that @torek is likely to be correct about this information not being stored/retrievable once the CLI output is no longer available.

Comment: Fair enough, sorry for that.

Comment: Don't worry about it. Besides, your response may yet help someone else.

Answer (score 1):

while still in merge state, if you run `git status`, you will find files under the section `Unmerged paths`, these are your conflicting files (Depending on the type of the conflict, the files will be marked as "both modified", "both added", "both deleted"...).

And to solve a conflict in general, if you use `git mergetool` it will go through the conflicting files automatically.

Comment: `git status` does not retrieve the exact list, it is a subset of the CLI message one gets initially upon merge conflict.

Comment: my apologies, I reworded to be more accurate (after having actually made a conflict and not answered by memory...), the whole list is under the "Unmerged paths" section.

Comment: As described, it is not the same list I am asking for. I am aware of `git status`, but it does not include reasons for the conflict and I am specifically asking for the list including entries such as: `CONFLICT (rename/rename): Rename <filepath> -> <filepath> in <branch>`. With `git status` I do not get that information. I will upvote your response for the effort and because it may solve someone's trouble with `git merge`, but it does not answer my question.